# SnappyData - inconsistent results deleting from column table

Tags: sql, snappydata

Reading through the documentation --> http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/rowAndColumnTables/#row-and-column-tables

I see that we should be able to perform DELETE FROM .... sql statements against row and column tables.  I am seeing inconsistent results when attempting to delete from a column table.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_COL (
    w_id VARCHAR(64),
    name VARCHAR(128),
    my_time TIMESTAMP,
    value VARCHAR(128),
    year_num INTEGER,
    month_num INTEGER
)
USING column 
OPTIONS(PARTITION_BY 'year_num, month_num', BUCKETS '113', PERSISTENT 'ASYNCHRONOUS');
```

Here is an example delete statement:

DELETE FROM MY_TABLE_COL where my_time >= '2016-08-10 00:00:00'

I've been attempting this query from Squirrel SQL and from the snappy-shell.  Sometimes a portion of the records I expect to be deleted will actually be deleted.  Other times, ZERO records are deleted.

I can wipe out all the data using the TRUNCATE TABLE MY_TABLE_COL command, but this will not work long term as we need to be able to selectively delete from a table.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: perhaps present some example data that did not delete how and when you expected using that statement.  otherwise we don't have any idea why it didn't delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supporting updates and deletes on column tables is on our roadmap but currently they are not supported. Updates and deletes are however supported on row tables.

For the inconsistencies that you are seeing, I have created two JIRAs.

https://jira.snappydata.io/browse/SNAP-988

https://jira.snappydata.io/browse/SNAP-989

Comment: thanks Hemant.  Looking forward to future updates.  In theory, in a production scenario, deleting data from a column table would not be a priority.